# What should be role value of div in html after apply onclick on div

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, onclick, accessibility

What should be the value of the role attribute when I apply onclick to a div.
I read the documentation [WAI-ARIA Roles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles), but not able to find any specific role value of a div. I am working in React and this component is inside a loop, on this component I have to go to another page when clicking on this component. What should be the value of the role attribute, If I do not use the role attribute then ES-Lint gives me a warning which is not acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On rereading your question, EDIT:  since you are performing a navigation  : `role ="link"`.

For actions, you need `role="button"`

**But, try to use the correct semantic whenever possible.**

Comment: Yes, it is performing an action.  I also think the button will be the value but want to confirm. Thanks buddy.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't read `have to go to another page when clicking on this component`. It is supposed to be a link as mentioned by @Graham. Actions are when you do something like `add to cart`, `delete`. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Screen readers and other technologies uses the role and semantics of the page to help guide the user.  Some of the commands in screen readers like "find links", "find buttons", "find headers" are important to helping the user experience.

Answer (score 2):

As it goes to another page - [`role="link"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_link_role) as it is effectively a hyperlink (`<a>`)

However if you have your routing set up correctly just swap your `<div>` for an anchor `<a>` and set the `href` attribute to the target.

With that being said [`role="link"` has good support](https://a11ysupport.io/tech/aria/link_role) so you should be fine with that.

Also consider that if this is a `<div>` then you need to add `tabindex="0"` to it so it can be focused with a keyboard and also handle the <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd> keys being pressed to also activate the link.

Much easier to use an `<a>` element from the start as you can imagine!

Comment: Thanks, Graham. It really helps to understand me tabIndex. Yes, I have to add a div tag instead of <a> tag.